# What is the best way to merge all tables in a database(POSTGRESQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have a database which is constantly updated with tennis match data. Each match that is analysed goes into a separate table within the database.
All these tables have the same column names, headers.

What I want is another table which is a vertical merge of all these matches. This table should update every time I add a new match to the original database.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Fix your data model!  Each match should be inserted into a *single* table.  Multiple small tables is highly suboptimal for databases -- they are designed to work with large tables.

Answer (score 2):

So, let's get this out of the way - a table per match is really not a good way of doing things. Each table corresponds to at least one on-disk file, some amount of metadata in the system catalogs, etc. Individual records should have not tables to themselves. But taking this state of affairs as a given, what you're asking for is pretty straightforward.

Create an empty table with the same structure, and set it as the [parent table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html) of the existing tables, and any new tables you create. You can then do what you're asking for by querying the parent table.

```
testdb=# create table t1(c1 text, c2 text);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# create table t2(c1 text, c2 text);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# insert into t1 select 'r1c1', 'r1c2';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into t2 select 'r2c1', 'r2c2';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# create table p(c1 text, c2 text);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# alter table t1 inherit p;
ALTER TABLE
testdb=# alter table t2 inherit p;
ALTER TABLE
testdb=# select * from p;
  c1  |  c2  
------+------
 r1c1 | r1c2
 r2c1 | r2c2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for this. 
So the reason why each match goes into a separate table is that one analysed match contains about 200 records pertaining to that match. These records are used in a BI tool for reporting. It seemed more sensible to import a table into the BI tool for reporting a match. 

Is there a better way of doing this?

I want the combination of all matches in a table for tracking and reporting historical data. Hence this question.

Comment: The question then is "When you import into the BI tool how do you identify which table"? You can then either create a look table or add the identifying columns to the existing table. Then use that data to identify the correct rows for a given match. Another possibility create a table with 1 row per match with same identifiers and another table contain the rows pertaining to each match. More detail on what you have, how you identify matches, will likely give you a better defined solution. Although, the results may just be opinions.

Comment: @Belayer You can use [tableoid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) you see which table the data came from; pass it through `::regclass::text` so it's converted to the table name instead of it's relation ID.